# KiCAD eeschem library part connecting pins together

Tags: kicad

I'm building a schematic library part for an Arduino prototype shield. Although it's a schematic part, I want it to look like the board as much as possible.

This board has two long lines of through holes that are connected to 5V and GND respectively. I can't figure out a good way to (A) create a long connnector or (B) create a bunch of pins that are all connected together or (C) make a wire.

The picture below shows my part so far with 5V and GND drawn as polylines. Is there a better way to do this?

[image]

I recognize that this may be a nonstandard way of using Library parts and EEschem. I'm using EEschem to make a wiring diagram. I suppose once I drop the part into my schematic, I can fake the 5V and GND lines with wires, but if there is a way to do it in the library part, that would be preferred.

**Edit:**

The solution I'm going with for now is to use the symbol as drawn above and trace over the 5V and GND polylines with a wire after I drop the symbol on the schematic. This symbol is part of a much larger wiring diagram and tools like Fritzing are really not appropriate. Dropping symbols on top of other symbols is not recommended, but I'm going to do it anyway. It works and is the best compromise for making a wiring diagram for which an Arduino prototyping boards is a small part. Editing is a little inconvenient because EEschem is always asking me which component I mean to be editing. But this is manageable.

Comment: How are you planning to connect external components to this symbol?

Comment: @Seth. To hook up external components, I drop SIP/DIP parts on the interior of the symbol and then add wires to the appropriate pins. For parts that are exterior to the board, I wire up to pins around the periphery. This scheme works fairly well on another prototyping board I used that lacked 5V and GND lines.

Comment: Are you hoping to run multiple connections to the 5V and ground lines (in multiple spots) and have them connect in eeschema?

Comment: @Seth. Yes, multiple connections to 5V and GND is the goal. Again this is a prototyping shield board for an Arduino. It has pins that plug into an Arduino and then there are lots and lots of 0.1" pitch metallized thru holes. And also a strip of connected holes for 5V and GND as depicted by polylines in the picture.

Comment: You could always make a number of 50-mil pins all named GND or 5V and place them in a line.  But really, this is backending something schematic representation is not meant to do.  From your description, I think Fritzing might be appropriate.

Comment: It is not a good practice to overlap symbols in schematic. I would recommend to use pins and connect the components next to the symbol. I agree with @Seth Fritzing looks more appropriate for what you are trying to do.